# MySQL + PHP - Get city from database based on postal code

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding, geocode

I have a MySQL table with about 10,000 rows, each containing a unique Postal Code.

I need to query the table and pull all rows that have a postal code within a specific city.

With an API like Google Geocode, I would need to pull all 10,000 results from the database, and then run each Postal Code through the API to filter through the city's.

If 30 rows have a Postal Code within Vancouver, I would like to find a way to get just those 30 rows. Is this possible?

Comment: `SELECT psc FROM table WHERE psc BETWEEN x AND x`
Like that?

Comment: Unfortunately provinces don't work like that. They are alphanumeric and are based on zones.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that some PSC are alphanumeric... Then idk

Comment: You also have to know that some countries do not have postcodes. That may have an impact on your query.

Comment: @grenoult This is for Canada only

Comment: @steeped there's actually a lot of countries, like Ireland.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your database more different.

For example one table with all the cities and another table with every postal code but every code has a city id.

Then your queries will be easier and you will have no more problems.

Comment: These 10,000 rows only have a postal code. It would probably make more sense if I instead just did the geocode lookup on import and store the city and province, but we re-import this data daily, and hitting the Google API 10,000 times a day will become very tedious.

Comment: why 10 000 times a day ? you can just do daily check for new post codes if there are new codes you will hit the api again. The other problem is to check if the data is still relevant you can split the postal codes in different patches for a cron. No need to do eveyrthing all together. After all postal coded don't change so often.